# possible to interpolate string with alphanumeric after variable name?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Say I have a variable dec, does a way way exist to specify in the string s"a $decimal" that $dec is the variable, and the rest are literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s"a ${dec}imal"
```

is the way to do it.  (Whenever you get in trouble, just make things explicit inside a `{}` block.)